# Ajuda com primeira rede neural

Tags: python, redes-neurais, tensorflow, keras

Sou iniciante em lidar com NNs, e preciso de ajuda e explicação em certas coisas com meu primeiro projeto.

Basicamento, to fazendo uma NN para damas, meu input são as partes pretas do board (8x4) preenchida com o estado: 0 vazio, 1 peça normal, 3 rainha. Positivo ou negativo simboliza se é aliada ou inimiga:

```
[[ 1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [-1. -1. -1. -1.]
 [-1. -1. -1. -1.]
 [-1. -1. -1. -1.]]
```

e o output são os movimentos possiveis, 4 para cada parte preta (32x4) ou (128x1), o index onde o '1' está mostra a peça e o movimento:

```
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
```

Meu banco de dados são 1000 partidas profissionais no modelo americano de damas, e transformei essas partidas em 200k de boards e movimentos

O Modelo que estou usando é um bem inspirado no do guia do tensorflow, eu só aumentei o número de layers e de neuronios e mudei loss para 'categorical_crossentropy', pois 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy' não funciona pro meu problema:

```
model = keras.Sequential([
        keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(8, 4)),
        keras.layers.Dense(1000, activation=tf.nn.relu),
        keras.layers.Dense(1000, activation=tf.nn.relu),
        keras.layers.Dense(1000, activation=tf.nn.relu),
        keras.layers.Dense(1000, activation=tf.nn.relu),
        keras.layers.Dense(1000, activation=tf.nn.relu),
        keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
    ])

model.compile(optimizer='adam', 
                  loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Com esse modelo minha NN consegue por volta de 50 épocas isto:

```
loss: 1.1787 - acc: 0.5935 - val_loss: 7.1449 - val_acc: 0.0840
```

E mais épocas muda quase nada, outro detalhe é que algumas épocas chegam a começar com 0.8 de acc mas no final caem pra 0.6, então preciso muito de ajuda no que fazer e por que, dicas de o que mudar no modelo, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Dados de Entrada

> 0 vazio, 1 peça normal, 3 rainha. Positivo ou negativo simboliza se é aliada ou inimiga

É chamado de [variável categórica](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vari%C3%A1vel_categ%C3%B3rica), a variável que mantenha dados que assumem um número limitado de valores possíveis, e sem relação numérica entre si.
A matriz de entrada do seu problema é composta de variáveis categóricas, pois não há [relação quantitativa](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vari%C3%A1vel_(estat%C3%ADstica)#Vari%C3%A1vel_Quantitativa) entre ter, por exemplo, uma peça branca ou uma peça preta em uma posição.

Infelizmente, redes neurais não operam bem em dados categóricos. Isso acontece porque cada neurônio da rede decidirá ativar-se ou não, a partir da aplicação de uma função de ativação em uma combinação linear dos valores de entrada, e assim sendo, ao se usar variáveis categóricas como entradas de neurônios, o usuário embute no classificador  uma hierarquia entre as chances de ativar um neurônio, informação tal que nem sempre é verdadeira.<sup>[1]</sup>

### Sugestão

A maneira mais simples de corrigir esta situação, é aplicar a codificação one-hot, que consiste em substituir variáveis categóricas por `N` variáveis numéricas simuladas<sup>[2]</sup>, capazes de assumir os valores `1` ou `0`, indicando se determinada categoria ocorre de fato ou não, sendo `N` o número de categorias que a variável original era capaz de assumir(no seu caso, `N=5`). É simples de programar esse processamento manualmente, mas se preferir também está presente na classe [OneHotEncoding](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) do scikit-learn.

## Dados de Saída

Se entendi bem, quando bem treinado, o seu programa irá mostrar sugestões de jogadas, a partir de um momento qualquer de um jogo. Mas o classificador sabe, apenas com os dados de entrada que você está usando, qual jogador pode se mover? Se você ainda não adicionou essa informação no classificador, o classificador irá fornecer palpites para ambos os jogadores a cada momento, embora você saiba que somente um dos jogadores tem a permissão de jogar. Essa informação extra pode ser adicionada no classificador para melhorar seu desempenho.

### Sugestão

Você pode adicionar a restrição, sem modificar a rede, com o seguinte pré-processamento:

1. Arbitre uma cor, que será a cor do jogador da vez, em todo o conjunto de dados
2. Quando ocorrer uma instância em que o tabuleiro é referente a um momento da partida em que é vez do jogador que você não escolheu, inverta as cores de todas as peças do tabuleiro

Isso seria o suficiente para que o classificador apenas "pense" na jogada ideal para o jogador que tem a permissão de jogar.

Finalmente, você pode reduzir a dimensão de saída, porque as peças nos cantos não podem se mover para fora do tabuleiro.

## Outras considerações

- Note que, apesar de ser improvável, nada impede que o classificador
  sugira um movimento que não é possível de ser feito de acordo com
  as regras. Caso queira fazer um bot, ou algo do tipo, lembre-se de validar o resultado dado pela rede neural com as regras.

---

<sup>[1] Adaptado [daqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22589081/4190915), original em inglês.</sup>

<sup>[2] Usei o termo `variável simulada` como tradução de [Dummy Variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dummy_variable_(statistics)).</sup>